# What spells are permanent?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Are there any spells that are permanent in 5th edition? By permanent, I mean a spell that doesn't end on its own, having a duration of "until dispelled", or not specifying when the spell ends.

I've found *magic mouth* which has a duration of "until dispelled" so it could potentially be permanent but what other spells are there?

Comment: More specifically, is there something you are *trying to do* that you need solved or is this more of a general question that isn't aimed at figuring something out?

Comment: This is a list question right?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting downvoted, it seems like a suitably good question for this stack, can someone enlighten me perhaps?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I'm re-reading the [meta question about list questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/what-are-list-questions). Linking it here for people interested.

Comment: @JamieBrace My guess is that it is because this is simply asking others to look through the books to find "Until Dispelled" or "Permanent" in spell descriptions.

Comment: @VoromirKadien Maybe not actually. One way to define list questions is  questions that have a non-finite or very very large amount of things that can go in the list thus making it impossible to get one answer with a concrete solution (see [what are list questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/what-are-list-questions?s=1|45.5509)).  My problem with this question is that it is essentially a legwork problem where OP is asking us to basically do a tedious task (that doesn't really involve expertise, only time) and that it doesn't seem to be solving any actual problem.

Comment: Agreed with @Rubiksmoose. This is not trying to solve any specific problem OP is having, it's just asking for a list of things (that don't solve a common problem either - it's different from "what spells do fire damage?" which might solve "I want to hit something vulnerable to fire"). Altho it's not a list question as defined in meta, it still "shows lack of research" and might be considered "not useful" by most people.

Comment: Are you looking for spells that maintain their "duration"? Example: Nystal's Magic Aura can become "Until Dispelled" which is the same as "Permanent" as both can be dispelled... durations of instantaneous are different in that they cannot be dispelled as their magic is done in creation of something. So are you asking for spells with infinite duration, or are you asking for spells that create things of lasting substance like Awaken or Wall of Stone? Because the two are slightly different.

Comment: I actually think that this can have a useful purpose. My Wizard (or the party) obtains a house or a ship. Given a few days (or months or years) of time, what permanent effects are likely to decorate this space? Arcane locks, of course. Continual flame in abundance, some wards, maybe some enhanced fortifications form Wall of Stone, etc. From a DM perspective, it helps flavor the world - what sort of amazing things are likely to be common in an NPC wizard's home or in a kingdom where the king employs wizards?

Comment: However, I agree that this is simply a shifting of work to the community, but it is a useful list for the community as well, so I'd argue it deserves to exist somewhere. Is that place here? That I don't know.

Comment: @NautArch An instantaneous spell *does* end on its own though... that is where I feel there is confusion and needs clarification. I know we are hashing this in the chat though.

Comment: [Read the book to me](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5270/22566) questions are not to be encouraged.

Comment: @cpcodes Your question is different than what was asked here. In your situation, spells that have a persistent consequence (Awaken, for example) would be helpful, while they seem to be not desired in this question, as OP wrote it. [Check our chat discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77703/discussion-between-slagmoth-and-nautarch) if you are interested. More specifically, your question is an actual thing you want to solve, which has some intersection with this question, but they are certainly not the same.

Comment: @cpcodes As another example of how they are different, while True Polymorph fits this question well, it certainly doesn't fit the scenario of a Wizard using a 9th level spell to... decorate his ship with a monster...? Finally, as you mentioned, even the decoration question might be more appropriate to a discussion forum as a Idea Generation question than to the SE format.

Comment: True that it is a list question. It is also an extremely useful question for anyone seeking to set up a permanent base of operations, or a permanent anything, to quickly look through your options. Personally I think a lot of the list question stigma is misplaced and against the spirit of SE as a font of useful knowledge. Who cares who does what legwork anyway, you are free to not answer the question. If he did the legwork himself and posted it as an answer, then that entire argument is defeated. That should not have a bearing on the question itself.

Answer (score 14):

## Here's a list*:

Spells that last permanently until dispelled or triggered:

- Animate Dead (control ends after 24 hours without recast, but remains Animated)
- Arcane Lock
- Awaken (Charm is lost after 30 days, but remains Awakened)
- Continual Flame
- Create or Destroy Water
- Drawmij's Instant Summons
- Druid Grove (daily casting for a year)
- Fabricate
- Forbiddance (daily casting for 30 days)
- Guards and Wards (daily casting for a year)
- Glyph of Warding (until triggered)
- Hallow
- Imprisonment
- Magic Jar
- Magic  Mouth
- Major Image (upcast to 6th+)
- Mighty Fortress (cast once every 7 days for a year)
- Modify Memory
- Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum (daily castings over a year)
- Nystal's Magic Aura (daily castings for 30 days)
- Programmed Illusion
- Sequester
- Simulacrum
- Symbol (until triggered)
- Teleportation Circle (daily castings over a year)
- Temple of the Gods (daily castings over a year)
- Transmute Rock
- True Polymorph (if concentrated on for full 1 hour duration)
- Wall of Stone (if concentrated on for full 10 minute duration)

*Official Content Only. Currently includes spells with instantaneous duration but continuing effects that can't be dispelled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77703/discussion-between-slagmoth-and-nautarch).

Comment: This list is missing Finger of Death (creates a permanently controlled Zombie)